# Why do you need a "!" in the tag <!DOCTYPE html> and what does it do?

Tags: html

It seems most tags don't have the !, but this one does.  I understand that concept of the DOCTYPE, just curious why it needs to have a "!".

Comment: To separate from similar doctypes that begin with `<?`, probably. tl;dr when the program encounters the `!`, it knows it's about to read a type declaration, which will tell it what kind of document the document is.

Answer (score 1):

HTML is based on [Standard Generalized Markup Language](http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/intro/sgmltut.html) (SGML), which is the standard used to define a document.

SGML uses the `<!` delimiter to specify meta-information, including Document Type Declarations (DTD). This is why it is used when marking up HTML documents.

> 3.1 Introduction to SGML
>
> SGML is a system for defining markup languages. Authors mark up their
>   documents by representing structural, presentational, and semantic
>   information alongside content. HTML is one example of a markup
>   language.

Answer (score 0):

I think it is the definition, without any reason! Just like you alias "Jeff Cooper" as your nick name.